# Performance Testing with pytest fixtures- yielf related error

Tags: python, pytest, fixtures

I am trying to implement a very basic simple performance testing using pytest, and modular fixtures.

I already have a fixture for time tracking:

```
@pytest.fixture
def time_tracker():
    tick = datetime.now()
    yield
    tock = datetime.now()
    diff = tock - tick
    print(f"\n runtime: {diff.total_seconds()}")
    return diff
```

I tried doing something like:

```
@pytest.fixture
def performance_testing(time_tracking):
    diff = time_tracking
    if diff > timedelta(seconds=30):
       raise ValueError("test is taking too long")
```

But I am having problems with the yield.
I think that when I am yielding from **time_tracker** then context goes back to the calling function which is **performance_testing** and not the test function itself.

My error:

```
@pytest.fixture
def performance_testing(time_tracker):
    diff = time_tracker

>       if diff > timedelta(seconds=30):
E       TypeError: '>' not supported between instances of 'NoneType' and 'datetime.timedelta'
```

I know I can easly implemnt this with duplicating the code and adding my `if diff > timedelta(30)` logic, however I want to use modular fixtures.

Is this possible? if not, is there an elegant "pytest" way of doing this?
Also, I am not intersted in downloading pytest plugins.

Comment: The error is that you are comparing `None` with time objects sind `yield` is the same as `yield None`. It has nothing to do with the context. Yield fixtures are not generators and treat `yield` differently; they do not return anything.

Answer (score 0):

`yield` is like `return` and can take an *argument*. Just write `yield tick` instead of just `yield`.